# Multiple file upload with smartphone using html and php

Tags: php, android, html, file-upload

I have a working html code where you can select multiple  files and upload them via POST to a php script, here is the code:

```
<form id="form_907007" class="appnitro" method="post" action="server/phpmailer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label class="description" for="File_upload">File_upload </label>

<div>
<input name="file[]" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000" multiple>
</div>
```

The code works perfect when I open the html form on my local computer, I tried it with firefox. I can select and upload as many files as I want to.

As "multiple" is part of html5 IE8 for Windows XP does not work anyway, is this the same problem with my smartphone?

On my smartphone (Android 4.1.2) I just can select one file to be upload, the upload works well but why I am not able to select multiple files? I use the "build-in" browser from android, nothing special.

Can you tell me where I have to improve my code to be able to select multiple files on smartphones, or is it just not possible?

Comment: saying "android" is rather pointless. that's like saying "windows". **WHICH** browser are you using in android? built-in? chrome? firefox?

Comment: I use the "built-in" browser, added some details to the question.

Comment: You should also post the Android version.

Comment: Android version 4.1.2

Answer (score -1):

HTML Markup

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This php code handles uploaded files and save to the server.

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*100; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not make any difference, the only thing thats different from my html code is "multiple" -> "multiple="multiple"". Your code works with firefox too but it does not work on the smartphone